# TypeScript errors after upgrading to 2.7.2

Tags: typescript, gulp, gruntjs, webstorm, tsc

I tried to update TypeScript on the project. Prev. version was 1.5, now it's 2.7.2.

I'm using JetBrains WebStorm, and it have built in TypeScript checker. Per that checker - there was few incompatibility errors, but I resolved them all.

But when I'm trying to compile that TypeScript by the Gulp or Grunt - I have a ton of errors, and everyone of them is like:

> Property 'Name' does not exist on type 'typeof Module'

All the project built by TS modules, and most of errors are on import statements, but some of them like:

> Property 'send' does not exist on type 'RESTRequest'

But that property exists in extended class. So WebStorm see it properly, but grunt / gulp does not.

Where can the problem be?

**package.json**

> Gulp deps
>
> ```
> "gulp": "^3.9.1",
> "gulp-typescript": "^4.0.1",
> "typescript": "^2.7.2"
> ```
>
> Grunt deps
>
> ```
> "grunt": "1.0.2",
> "grunt-ts": "^6.0.0-beta.17"
> "typescript": "^2.7.2"
> ```

WebStorm is using 2.7.2 TS version and 8.9.4 Node for compile check.

Comment: Without some sample code it is difficult to say what the problem is

Comment: Project is really huge, don't really think that may provide a sample, but as though - grunt & gulp working if provide compiled d.ts files in reference, but didn't work without them

Comment: A sample, just one :)

Comment: Do you have tsconfig file? Do you use it when running with gulp?

Comment: Will try to find something, but updated the previous comment, check it please

Comment: Yes, there's a tsconfig in the root. But it's not possible to use it with grunt / gulp, the project is a combination of bundles, e.g. one module may be needed at many places, and when I try to use tsconfig - it compiles all the bundles to one file

Comment: You need at least to specify same compiler options

Comment: In webstorm I don't really see any options for ts. But I alreasy providing needed files & options to gulp such as target ecma & defs compiling

Comment: Webstorm picks up tsconfig automatically.